# lighttpd url rewrite per vhost

Tags: mod-rewrite, lighttpd

I have a lighttpd webserver running simple vhosts. I would like to do an url rewrite for just one of the hosts. I tried this in `/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf`:

```
$HTTP["host"] == "api.sitename.com" {
  server.document-root = "/var/www/api.sitename.com/"
  accesslog.filename = "/var/log/lighttpd/api.sitename.access.log"
  url.rewrite = ( "^(.*)$" => "/index.php?$1" )
}
```

For use with an API. (https://github.com/alixaxel/ArrestDB)

Answer (score 1):

```
url.rewrite = ( "^(.*)$" => "/index.php/$1" )

change :                               ^
                                       from ? to /
```